# A homogeneous linear system $\textbf{Ax}=\textbf{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

Consider a homogeneous system $\textbf{Ax}=\textbf{0}$ whose coefficient matrix is

$$\textbf{A}= \begin{pmatrix}
 x_{1}^{2}&  x_{1}y_{1}&  y_{1}^{2}&  x_{1}&  y_{1}&  1\\ 
 x_{2}^{2}&  x_{2}y_{2}&  y_{2}^{2}&  x_{2}&  y_{2}&  1 \\ 
 x_{3}^{2}&  x_{3}y_{3}&  y_{3}^{2}&  x_{3}&  y_{3}&  1 \\ 
 x_{4}^{2}&  x_{4}y_{4}&  y_{4}^{2}&  x_{4}&  y_{4}&  1\\ 
 x_{5}^{2}&  x_{5}y_{5}&  y_{5}^{2}&  x_{5}&  y_{5}&  1 
\end{pmatrix}\in Mat(\mathbf{R} ;5\times 6 ) .$$  $$ \textbf{x}= \begin{pmatrix}
A\\ 
B\\ 
C\\ 
D\\ 
E\\
F 
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbf{R^6};\qquad\textbf{0}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Show that

$rank(\textbf{A})=5;$ there is an $\mathbf{x} $ such that $\textbf{Ax}=\textbf{0}$ and $\det(\begin{pmatrix}
 2A&  B&  D \\ 
  B& 2C& E \\ 
 D&  E&  2F \
\end{pmatrix})\ne 0$.$\Longleftrightarrow $ For any $ k_{1},k_{2},k_{3}\in \{1,2,3,4,5\} $ and $k_{1}<k_{2}<k_{3}$, $ rank\begin{pmatrix}
 x_{k_{1}}&  y_{k_{1}}& 1\\ 
 x_{k_{2}}&  y_{k_{2}}& 1 \\ 
 x_{k_{3}}&  y_{k_{3}}& 1
 \end{pmatrix}=3.$

I want to apply only the knowledge of linear algebra to proof " There is a unique conic through any five points in a real plane, and it is nondegenerate if and only if no three of the points are collinear ."

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: Showing rank(A) = 5 depends on the points, is it given that no 3 points are collinear?

Comment: Have you tried using Gaus-Jordan elimination and seeing what you get when reducing matrix A?

Comment: This looks weirdly similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776356/proof-any-five-points-determine-a-conic?rq=1), right down to the same inconsistent spacing of line break characters in the source code of the matrices. What's going on here?

Comment: @KReiser:Sorry,I copied that post's codes,with no changes. Thanks for your edit! +1

Comment: Look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542374/matrix-of-constraints-shows-that-a-conic-is-determined-uniquely), especially the last answer.