# Given any 5 distinct points in $\mathbb {CP}^2$, there exists projective conic in $\mathbb {CP}^2$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given any 5 distinct points in $\mathbb {CP}^2$, there exists projective conic in $\mathbb {CP}^2$.

I saw the solutions there:[Proof any five points determine a conic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776356/proof-any-five-points-determine-a-conic)

But this is not same we have triples as points in $\mathbb {CP}^2$ as $[a:b:c]$ and conic is element of $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]$.

Write the general conic here as $$H=aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2+dXY+eXZ+fYZ=0$$

Given points be $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_5$, $p_i=[a_i:b_i:c_i]$

Now we have to solve the below matrix equation:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_1^2& b_1^2 & c_1^2 & a_1b_1 & a_1c_1 & b_1c_1 \\
a_2^2& b_2^2 & c_2^2 & a_2b_2 & a_2c_2 & b_2c_2 \\
a_3^2& b_3^2 & c_3^2 & a_3b_3 & a_3c_3 & b_3c_3 \\
a_4^2& b_4^2 & c_4^2 & a_4b_4 & a_4c_4 & b_4c_4 \\
a_5^2& b_5^2 & c_5^2 & a_5b_5 & a_5c_5 & b_5c_5 \\
\end{pmatrix}_{5\times 6}\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\\ d\\ e\\ f\end{pmatrix}_{6\times 1}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

and so on, But I want to solve the problem in an elegant way, with using the tools of Algebraic Curves in Projective Plane on algebraicaly closed field in this case it is $\mathbb C$

**Edit:**

The meaning of searching elegant method is that using the property of the projective plane such as, every two projective line is intersects only at a point. I thought that there may be some methods that we can reduce the 5 distinct point into more simple setup and then at the and we may end up with trivial solution that provides the desired conic(at least one such conic).

Comment: This matrix method is short and simple. What sort of "elegant way" are you looking for? In what ways do you want to improve on this solution? (Let me also remark that this is the same problem as in the link once you make a suitable choice of a line at infinity containing none of your 5 points and dehomogenize appropriately.)

Comment: Okay but what do you mean about equivalating the problem here and the one in the link? "suitable choice of a line at infinity containing none of your 5 points." And how do we know about solution to this matrix system?

Comment: 1. Choose coordinates so that the $z$-coordinate of all of your points is nonzero. Then all of your points lie in the copy of $\Bbb A^2$ given by $[x:y:1]$. Run the solution from the link, homogenize the polynomial you get with respect to $z$, and you have a solution  for your original problem after undoing your original coordinate change. 2. Your matrix is a map from a six-dimensional vector space to a five-dimensional vector space. Therefore it has a nontrivial kernel.

Comment: I understood the solution now, thank you but only flaw in my head is now "Choose coordinates so that the z-coordinate of all of your points is nonzero" because let assume one of the point is given by $p_i=[1:i:0]$ how can I change the coordinates the make it nonzero in $Z$? because I have no control on given points. May be  we can do it for others but again maybe we have $[1:0:0],[0:1:0],[0:0:1]$ along given points so we cant do the trick? What am I missing?

Comment: Find a line which does not pass through any of the points. Translate this line so it's $V(z)$ by an action of $Aut(\Bbb P^2)=PGL_3$. ("Coordinate change" does not simply mean permute $x$, $y$, and $z$.) Now please, we are far afield from your original question - please [edit] your post to explain what sort of elegance you're looking for over the solution you've got there.